# EF6 model first - The entity type is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I know questions about this issue have already been asked dozens of times (I've read them all) but I am still left with no solution.
Most deal with issues that can happen with code-first design, but I am doing model-first.

I am familiar with EF, and have other working models in my solution.

- WPF (net 4.5)
- Entity Framework 6.1.3 - **Model First**
- Visual Studio 2013

**Problem**:

*Every* DbSet<> in my context throws the following error when being accessed:

"An exception of type '*System.InvalidOperationException*' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: **The entity type xxx is not part of the model for the current context**.
"

**How I created the model:**

1. new project
2. add edmx - include tables model first
3. made the entities inherit from a base class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged
4. removed the base class and modified the .tt file so the entities implement INotifyPropertyChanged instead
5. (Deleted everything and tried again from scratch)

**Connection String:**

```
<add name="Stratus_X_TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PartsServiceModel.csdl|res://*/PartsServiceModel.ssdl|res://*/PartsServiceModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Stratus;initial catalog=StratusX;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This connection string is the same as the conenction string from a different (and working!) .edmx in my solution.

**Usage:**

```
using (var ObjectContext = new TestEntities())
{
    return ObjectContext.AccountingType.ToList();
}
```

TestEntities is DbContext. 
Any attempt to access ObjectContext.AccountingType, or **any** other DbSet<> results in the error.

**Things I have checked:**

- The Connection String (Model First - See above)
- Entities mapped correctly? yes
- Mulitple instances or generations of entity types - no
- Is the Entities inheriting from a base classes causing the error? 
  no, I removed the base class and made the .tt file generate the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation in the entities directly. Error persists!
- View the Model/Entity Diagram (*.edmx). Right click the offending Table, and Validate.
- Read every similar SO question for ideas
- Replicate the project in a test solution: **it works in a separate solution!**
- Move the test project into working solution: same error!

**Can anyone think of anything else to try/check??**

thanks

Comment: does your connection string have the correct ssdl/mdl/csdl file names? tried cleaning the solution?

Comment: oh brilliant thanks! I didn't realize the  ssdl/mdl/csdl bits were different. I have two models connecting to the same database, so naturally they come out with the same name. I had to rename one and make sure they were both in my main App.Config file, now it works properly!

Answer (score 0):

If everything looks good, just remove the object from edmx and re-add. Somehow EF lost some connection inside. Doing so fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to EF, and .NET, but i think that by default EF will search for a connection string with **the same name as the context's class name**, so, may be,
if you change the connection string name to "**TestEntities**", it might do the trick.